# Why FPDF's useImportedPage doesn't work for PHP code

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

I receive the following error when using `useImportedPage()` for generating labels...

> ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to undefined method
>   FPDI::useImportedPage().

But when I comment out `$pdf->useImportedPage($tplIdx, 10, 10, 100);` 
and un-comment line `$pdf->useTemplate($tplidx);` it works fine.

The PDF I import is version 1.4.

Any suggestions as to why `useImportedPage()` doesn't work?

```
    $this->auto_render  = false;
    $this->template = NULL;
    $offset = 0;

    require_once('assets/vendors/fpdf/fpdf.php');
    require_once('assets/vendors/fpdi/fpdi.php');

    $pdf = new Fpdi();

    $pdf->addPage();

    $pdf->setSourceFile('TEST.pdf');

    $tplidx = $pdf->importPage(1);

    $pdf->useImportedPage($tplIdx, 10, 10, 100);
    //$pdf->useTemplate($tplidx);

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial');
    $pdf->SetFontSize(5);
    $pdf->SetXY(5, 5);
    $pdf->Text(3.5, 5, $_POST['A']);
    $pdf->Text(3.5, 8.5, $_POST['B']);
    $pdf->Text(21, 5, $_POST['C']);
    $pdf->Text(21, 8.3, $_POST['D']);
    $filename='SECONDTEST/'.$_POST['A'].'.pdf';
    $pdf->Output($filename, 'F');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the outdated version 1.x. `useImportedPage()` was added in FPDI 2.